"Modulus of convexity" v.s. "Modulus of a uniformly convex function"
I have found two words seemingly related to each other, but I cannot make a connection.
Definition. (Modulus of convexity, Wikipedia)
The modulus of convexity of a Banach space $(X,\|\cdot \|)$ is the function $\delta:[0,2]\to [0,1]$ defined by
$\displaystyle \delta(\epsilon) = \inf\left\{1-\left\|\frac{x+y}{2}\right\|:x,y\in S,\|x-y\|\geq \epsilon\right\}\tag*{}$
where $S$ denotes the unit sphere of $(X,\|\cdot\|$).
Definition. (Uniformly convex function, Wikipedia)
A uniformly convex function with modulus $\phi$ is a function $f$ that, for all $x,y$ in the domain and $t\in[0,1]$, satisfies
$f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y) - t(1-t)\phi(\|x-y\|)$
Question.
They use the same word, modulus. Are they related to each other (for example, is the modulus of convexity a modulus for the norm $\|\|$ and vice versa?) Or is it just a coincidence?

By definition
$$
\delta( \epsilon) \le 1 - \frac12 \|x+y\|
$$
for all $x,y\in S$ with $\|x-y\| \ge \epsilon$. This is equivalent
to
$$
\frac12 \|x+y\|  + \delta( \epsilon) \le \frac12( \|x\| + \|y\|)
$$
for all $x,y\in S$ with $\|x-y\| \ge \epsilon$. So the modulus of convexity, measures the convexity of the norm (or the convexity of the unit ball).

It is my impression that the notion ''modulus of X'' is an attempt to quantify how certain objects satisfy property X. There is also a modulus of continuity, which quantifies continuity (or uniform continuity).
